# Python: calculate std in the filtered rows

Tags: python, pandas

Original data

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import random
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["date", "7 days return"])
date = datetime.datetime.strptime("2019-01-04", '%Y-%m-%d')
for i in range(365*3):
    df = df.append({"date": date + datetime.timedelta(i), "7 days return":random.uniform(0,1)}, ignore_index=True)
df
```

Out:

| date | 7 days return |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-01-04 | 0.780342 |
| 2019-01-05 | 0.7238 |
| 2019-01-06 | 0.02408 |
| 2019-01-07 | 0.188626 |
| 2019-01-08 | 0.255635 |
| ... | ... |
| 2021-12-26 | 0.833696 |
| 2021-12-27 | 0.806889 |
| 2021-12-28 | 0.902588 |
| 2021-12-29 | 0.833696 |
| 2021-12-30 | 0.806889 |
| 2021-12-31 | 0.902588 |
| 2022-01-01 | 0.182522 |
| 2022-01-02 | 0.612269 |

I need to calculate the standard deviations in the recent 365 rows but only use the last row of every 7 rows. For example, if I want to calculate the number for the date 2022-01-02, I only use the rows indexed with 2022-01-02, 2021-12-26, 2021-12-19, 2021-12-12, 2021-12-05 and so on in the recent 1 year. If calculate the number for the date 2022-01-01, I only need the rows indexed with 2022-01-01, 2021-12-25, 2021-12-18, 2021-12-11 and so on in the recent 1 year.

To achieve such results, I coded as followed:

```
a=[]
for i in range(0,len(df),7):
    a.append(i)
Volatility1Y=df.iloc[a].transform(lambda x:x.rolling(52).std())
```

But it outputed the results also every 7 days, which is different from the results I need. I need to calculate the standard deviation everyday.

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for:

```py
volatility_1y = (
    df.groupby(df["date"].dt.dayofweek)["7 days return"]
    .rolling(52).std()
    .droplevel(level=0).sort_index()
)
```

Essentially: Use `.rolling(52)` on sub-series of `df["7 days return"]` defined by the day of the week. (If so, you might want to look into the `min_periods` keyword argument of `.rolling` because otherwise you'll get a lot of `NaN`s.)

Btw., you can create your dataframe much more efficient with something like (`.append` is depreciated since version 1.4.0):

```py
from random import random

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date": pd.date_range(start="2019-01-04", periods=365 * 3),
    "7 days return": [random() for _ in range(365 * 3)]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct:

```py
a = []
for i in range(7):
    # for each day of week
    df_temp = df[i::7].copy()
    # calculate rolling std
    df_temp['var'] = df_temp['7 days return'].rolling(52).std()
    a.append(
        df_temp
    )
    
result = pd.concat(a, ignore_index=True)

# sort in the end
result.sort_values('date')
```